# Why doesn't perl inplace editing work if I read user input before that?

Tags: perl, inplace-editing

I am trying to edit a cfg file inplace inside a perl script, but it doesn't work if I read user input before that. Here is a test script to recreate the problem I am seeing.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $TRACE_CFG = "trace.cfg";

print "Continue [y/N]> ";
my $continue = <>;

{
    local $^I = '.bak';
    local @ARGV = ($TRACE_CFG);

    while (<>) {
        s/search/replace/;
        print;
    }

    unlink("$TRACE_CFG.bak");
}
```

The edit works if I comment out the "my $continue = <>;" line. If I do read user input, it looks like setting @ARGV to trace.cfg file doesn't take effect and the while loop waits for input from STDIN. I can work around this by using sed or using a temporary file and renaming it, but I would like to know the reason for this behaviour and the correct way to do this.

Comment: I never realized this. "Neat".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try,

```
my $continue = <STDIN>;
```

instead of

```
my $continue = <>;
```

as `<>` has magic which opens `-` file handle, and does not look later on what is in `@ARGV`, thus not processing your files.

Answer (score 5):

According to [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators):

> Input from <> comes either from standard input, or from each file listed on the command line. Here's how it works: the **first time** <> is evaluated, the @ARGV array is checked, and if it is empty, $ARGV[0] is set to "-", which when opened gives you standard input. The @ARGV array is then processed as a list of filenames.
>
> You can modify @ARGV **before** the first <> as long as the array ends up containing the list of filenames you really want.